# Facebook API - search people refined by company name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

In the web UI on Facebook you can do a search for a person refined by company name.  Is it possible to do this in the API as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't possible in the API at present - the search documentation is at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching

Comment: Thanks.  Wasn't sure if this was all they offered or if the docs were simply incomplete.